# Error "The proposed data changes would violate a uniqueness constraint." Sandbox specific problem?

Tags: sandbox, unique-field

In my partial data sandbox, I get this error when saving edits to any existing Account. I have enabled the finest debug levels, but the debug log does not give any clue as to why I get this message.

When googling, people tell you that a unique field is to blame. OK, I have some unique fields, but a) which one is to blame? and b) I don't understand why changes to Accounts in production don't cause the same error. It only occurs in the sandbox.

When I create a new Account in the sandbox, I can edit it just fine, no problems with unicity.

The sandbox is Summer'18, so the same version as in production.

Edit: after more tries, I noticed that the error manifests itself in two ways: one as the message in bold red, on the Account edit page. And one as a new page, with the message: "Data Uniqueness Violation. The proposed data changes would violate a uniqueness constraint."

So:

[image]

and:

[image]

Update: I thought I'd update the record via the Workbench, maybe I would get a better error message that way. To my surprise, the edit that can't be saved via Classic UI, can be made via the Workbench. I tried the edit again with the UI: error. With the Workbench: success. So this error is not on the database level, but somewhere else? I have no validation rules that give this message, what could it be?

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if you found a solution but I have the same issue each time I refresh a sandbox with data I have this issue with all data created during the refresh. 
What I do to solve it, is to create a ticket with Salesforce support and have them run a scrutiny job. The ticket looks like this:

We cannot create edit accounts in our sandbox after refresh, we can create new, but not edit accounts that was there after refresh.​
Reference to Case: ------

Tier 3 team previously solved this problem by running this Scrutiny: 
Ran the scrutiny and it fixed the issue. 
Organization Id: ??

Maximum quick rows: 100

Tasks: 
ObjTerr2AssociationAccShareExtraActiveModel: Run-fix-COMMIT

ObjTerr2AssociationAccShareExtraActiveModel: found 22183, fixed 22183, remaining 0, commit in 20 sec

It is also possible to uncheck the "Evaluate this account against territory rules on save" at the bottom of the page.

Hope that this helps.

Best regards, 
Christian.

Comment: Thanks. I still have this problem, so I will keep your suggestions in mind!